# Saving multiple row with counterCache

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I have problem with counterCache in cakePHP 2.6.4.
I need to save multiple rows to `bloggers_products` table and i want to increment `Bloggers.products_all` for each product. For now `products_all` is allways incremented once.

```
BloggersProduct belongsTo Blogger
Blogger hasMany BloggersProduct
```

BloggersProduct Model

```
'Blogger' => array(
        'className' => 'Blogger',
        'counterCache' => array(
            'products_all' => true,
            'reviews' => array('NOT' => array('BloggersProduct.review' => '0000-00-00'))
        )
        )
```

I was trying to save data in loop and with `saveMany`.

```
        $i = 0;
        $save = [];
        $this->loadModel('BloggersProduct');
        foreach ($data as $product) {
//                $save = [];
//                $save['product_id'] = intval($product);
//                $save['blogger_id'] = $blogger_id;
//                $save['send_at'] = date('Y-m-d', time());
//               
//                $this->BloggersProduct->create();
//                $this->BloggersProduct->save($save, array('counterCache' => true));

            $save[$i]['product_id'] = intval($product);
            $save[$i]['blogger_id'] = $blogger_id;
            $save[$i]['send_at'] = date('Y-m-d', time());
            $i++;
        }

        debug($save);

        $res = $this->BloggersProduct->saveMany($save, array('counterCache' => true));
```

When i edit or delete any of related products counters set to true value.

Comment: I try set bloggers_product_count in bloggers table, use default cake setting and get the same result.
saveAll, saveMany, set ClassName, foreignKey, checked afterSave callback - counterCache = true. I waste whole day try everything and still dont do single step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simple:

```
$this->YourModel->cacheQueries = false;
```